# Unknown OSGi execution environment: 'JavaSE-21'

Tags: maven, osgi, eclipse-rcp, tycho, java-21

I try to upgrade an Eclipse RCP project from `Java 17` o `Java 21`. The project is currently using Eclipse Target Platform `2023-12`.

***2023-12.target***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="3.8"?>
<target name="Retrospective (2023-12)">
    <locations>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
            <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2023-12/"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.sdk.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.sdk.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
        </location>
    </locations>
</target>
```

***pom.xml***

```
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho-version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho-version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <resolver>p2</resolver>
        <target>
            <artifact>
                <groupId>com.retrospective</groupId>
                <artifactId>com.retrospective.target</artifactId>
                <version>6.2.0</version>
                <classifier>2023-12</classifier>
            </artifact>
        </target>
        ...
```

What I did so far:

- Switched to `Java 21 JDK` inside Eclipse
- Updated project version in `pom.xml` and `.product` files
- Defined `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=21` in the `.product` file
- Upgraded `maven` to version 3.9.6
- Upgraded `tycho` to version 4.0.5
- Defined `Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-21` in all `MANIFEST.MF` files
- Updated version of a few libraries
- Got the project to compile inside Eclipse and successfully launched the application on my computer

When I push my changes to GIT, the `CI/CD` build job starts but produces an error. I can reproduce the same error when running `mvn clean verify -e` locally:

```
Unknown OSGi execution environment: 'JavaSE-21'
org.eclipse.tycho.core.ee.UnknownEnvironmentException: Unknown OSGi execution environment: 'JavaSE-21'
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.ee.ExecutionEnvironmentUtils.getExecutionEnvironment (ExecutionEnvironmentUtils.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.OsgiBundleProject.applyBestOfCurrentOrConfiguredProfile (OsgiBundleProject.java:642)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.OsgiBundleProject.readExecutionEnvironmentConfiguration (OsgiBundleProject.java:617)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.TychoProjectManager.lambda$getExecutionEnvironmentConfiguration$0 (TychoProjectManager.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.DefaultReactorProject$LazyValue.get (DefaultReactorProject.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.DefaultReactorProject.computeContextValue (DefaultReactorProject.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.TychoProjectManager.getExecutionEnvironmentConfiguration (TychoProjectManager.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2resolver.P2DependencyResolver.lambda$getPreliminaryTargetPlatform$3 (P2DependencyResolver.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.DefaultReactorProject$LazyValue.get (DefaultReactorProject.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.DefaultReactorProject.computeContextValue (DefaultReactorProject.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2resolver.P2DependencyResolver.getPreliminaryTargetPlatform (P2DependencyResolver.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.AbstractTychoProject.lambda$getDependencyArtifacts$0 (AbstractTychoProject.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.DefaultReactorProject$LazyValue.get (DefaultReactorProject.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.DefaultReactorProject.computeContextValue (DefaultReactorProject.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.AbstractTychoProject.getDependencyArtifacts (AbstractTychoProject.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoResolver.resolveProject (DefaultTychoResolver.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoProjectExecutionListener.beforeProjectLifecycleExecution (TychoProjectExecutionListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.CompoundProjectExecutionListener.beforeProjectLifecycleExecution (CompoundProjectExecutionListener.java:42)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:103)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
```

Which important migration step have I forgotten?

Comment: Does in the configuration of your target-platform-configuration [`<resolveWithExecutionEnvironmentConstraints>false</resolveWithExecutionEnvironmentConstraints>`](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/blob/ea6960e6ee6c31ef96ec12c34d8f94e7ab0e40dd/pom.xml#L131C29-L131C123) help?

Comment: Have you more log output you could show with that error in context?

Comment: @howlger:  Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately `<resolveWithExecutionEnvironmentConstraints>` did not help.

Comment: @nitind: I run `mvn`  with `-e` option and added the printed stacktrace to my question.

Comment: Run `mvn` also with `-v` and double-check whether Maven is actually run with Java 21 (if you use Maven with toolchains, say so). Please show your Maven log, not only the stack trace of it.

Comment: Especial check the maven log for the tycho version - I get `[INFO] Tycho Version:  4.0.5 (bc6c4158d7b008797d3e85c0dae0ccd9e50458e5)`

Comment: @howlger: `mvn -v` revealed that the wrong Java version was still used. I locally changed the `JAVA_HOME` env variable and the corresponding setting for the Azure build pipeline and now it works. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to **run your CI/CD Maven build with Java 21**.

To get the version of Maven and Java at the beginning of the log, use the [Maven command line option **`-V`** or `--show-version`](https://maven.apache.org/ref/4-LATEST/maven-embedder/cli.html).

In general, for CI/CD Maven builds the following options might be helpful:

- `-V` - Display Maven and Java version information without stopping the build
- `-ntp` - Do not display transfer progress when downloading or uploading
- `-fae` - Only fail the build afterwards; allow all non-impacted builds to continue

Comment: that does not help in my case. Maven is running on Java 17 (as version query prints) and the MANIFEST.MF says: `Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-17` the error comes anyway. i suggest Tycho 4.0.0 cannot handle this any more... will try to downgrade Tycho

Comment: @freshNfunky Your case is a different case. The current Tycho version is 4.0.4, and further downgrading sounds to me like a bad idea. Maybe the configuration of your target-platform-configuration is just missing `<resolveWithExecutionEnvironmentConstraints>false</resolveWithExecutionEnvironmentConstraints>` (see my comment to the question).

Comment: Sorry @howlger the Origin of the Error originated from a bundeled execution environment: 
`<plugin>`  
`<groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>`
`<artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>`
`<version>${tycho.version}</version>`
`<configuration>`
`<executionEnvironment>org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full-${java.version}</executionEnvironment>`